# How to implement "turn off music" button Android

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I want to add a button in my application that turns off the music but I don't know how to approach it, I have an idea but I'm sure it's far from best so I want to consult with you. The situation is as follows:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {


MediaPlayer easysong;
MediaPlayer normalsong;
MediaPlayer hardsong;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.land_main);

    mContext = this;
    restartButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.restartButton);

    restartButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            easysong = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.arideniro);
            normalsong = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.junior);
            hardsong = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.ketsathis);
            counter = 101;
            i = 500 - dif;

            new Thread(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {
                    if(i==500){
                    easysong.start();}
                    else if(i==375){
                        normalsong.start();
                    }else if(i==250){
                        hardsong.start();
                    }
                    while (counter > 0) {
                        try {

                            Thread.sleep(i);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        counter--;
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                scoreText.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
                            }
                        });
                        if(i>150){
                            i/=1.01;}
                        else if(i>90-(dif/10)){
                            i-=1;
                        }
                    }if (counter==0) {
                        mChronometer.stop();
                        if(easysong.isPlaying()) {
                            easysong.stop();
                            easysong.release();
                            easysong = null;
                        }else if(normalsong.isPlaying()){
                            normalsong.stop();
                            normalsong.release();
                            normalsong = null;
                        }else if(hardsong.isPlaying()){
                        hardsong.stop();
                        hardsong.release();
                            hardsong = null;
                        }
```

This is the main class of my app where the mediaplayer is used, now I deleted much of the code because it was irrelevant to the mediaplayer and the question, so don't look for the missing brackets and such. And this here is the main menu class where the Switch that will turn on and off the music will be located:

```
public class MainMenu extends Activity{

private Button easy;
private Button normal;
private Button hard;
private Button scores;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_menu);

    easy = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_easy);
    scores = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_highscores);

    easy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dif = 0;
            startGame();
        }
    });
}
public void startGame() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainMenu.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

So my idea is simnple, to add a variable in MainActivity like "int p;" and from the MainMenu class to change it's state between 0 and 1, then I will add around each line that starts music an if(p==1) but is this a good approach ? Also I would like the value of the int to be saved when the app is closed

Comment: Media player has got a method setVolume - [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html)

Comment: The above is if you want to mute the sound, if you want to pause player at all call `pause`. To know if mediaPlayer is playing, you unfortunately have to keep its state in a variable as you wrote.